# client denied by server configuration: /app/etc/config.php

Tags: magento-2.1

I am currently facing a weird issue.The admin session is being destroyed and admin is being logged out when the admin tries to click on any tab on the store configuration.

**What i figured out?**

I have used a theme for my store and an extension for multi-vendor.I figured out that there is module incompatibility between theme module and another module. Individually both of those modules function properly but when both are enabled there is issue of admin logout when admin tries to change the system configuration.

/********* Update ***************/

I checked the Apache log and it says:

> [Wed Oct 05 10:57:59.355737 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 7300:tid
>   1740] [client 192.168.0.90:57108] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: E:/xampp/htdocs/projectname/app/etc/config.php

I guess It suggests that the config.php is tried to opened directly or likewise, not sure.

/**********Update ends **********/

**What help I expect?**

I think it is very difficult to figure out the issue without seeing the codes but if anyone could answer the types of conflicts that could arise on modules on Magento 2 which could give issue of such behavior.

**What i did?**

I commented the content on system.xml file of a theme module and tested as there is issue only when the admin click the system configuration tab but it didn't worked.

So could anyone help me out here to figure out the issue or suggest the way of debugging to figure out the issue.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You can update your first question if you want to add more details, or offer a bounty if you want it to receive more attention.

Comment: Thank you guys for the suggestion, i will keep that in mind.